# inserting a long string into a textarea with casperjs fails

Tags: javascript, string, limit, casperjs, legacy

I'm working with a legacy system where developers must copy and paste their css into a textarea.

I'm trying to automate this "work flow" by running casperjs to login to the system, navigate to the appropriate page and fill in the textarea.

Unfortunately, I think I'm hitting a string limit when it comes to filling out forms. The minified css is about 300000 characters long. If I substr the css file and insert a 100000 long string, the form submits and saves.

This may be a long shot but I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to overcome this limitation? For this problem, please assume that I am forced to stay within the confines of this legacy system where I *must* copy and paste into a textarea. For example, I have no direct access to a server's file system, nor can I host the file in a third party cdn

```
casper.then(function(){
    var longstring = fs.read('path/to/long.min.css');
    this.fill('#form', {
        'css': longstring   
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `#css` is correct? It must be the name of the textarea not its id and also not a selector. You might try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5df918e93d4f4f266587). I cannot reproduce the problem on Win7 32bit with phantomjs 1.9.7-9.

Comment: @ArtjomB. You're right, that snippet I provided is wrong (I rewrote it to remove sensitive info). I've updated to be the name of the textarea and not its ID. However, the same issue still applies -- I think it's just a limit I'm going to have to work with (I mean 300000 long string is kind of ridiculous)

Comment: Is it a `<textarea>` or an `<input>` element?

Comment: Do you see an error with the script I provided in the linked [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5df918e93d4f4f266587)?

Comment: @dave definitely textarea.
@ArtjomB Running the first gist, I don't get any errors in the console. However, modifying the iterations to 31, I get an Out of memory error. So that's interesting since 31 iterations yields a string length of 2147483648 (way more than my 300000).

After talking to some colleagues, I'm thinking of just POSTing the string to the form's action in casper using `this.open`